# Compare and rewrite URL with mod_rewrite based on path and query string

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have URLs in a scheme

```
/([0-9]*)/some/path/script.jsf?someId=([0-9]*)
```

and I'd like to redirect to $2 the user if $1 doesn't match $2. So for example if the user requests

```
/1/some/path/script.jsf?someId=1
```

everthing is fine and the user shouldn't be redirected but if the user requests

```
/1/some/path/script.jsf?someId=2
```

the user should be redirected to

```
/2/some/path/script.jsf?someId=2
```

I've tried this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9]*)/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} someId=([0-9]*)
RewriteCond %1 !%2
RewriteRule (.*) /%2/some/path/script.jsf?someId=%2 [R]
```

but %2 seems always empty. So I've tried this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9]*)/some/path/script.jsf?someId=([0-9]*)
RewriteCond %1 !%2
RewriteRule (.*) /%2/)/some/path/script.jsf?someId=%2 [R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%n` only accesses backreferences from

> the last matched `RewriteCond` in the current set of conditions.

That's why your `%2` always seems empty in your first set of rules.

Your second attempt gets around this problem for the `RewriteCond %1 !%2`, but you can't refer to `%2` in your `RewriteRule`, as it refers to, again, the *last matched `RewriteCond`*.

If you're running Apache 2, there's a very simple way to do this using a negative lookahead assertion:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]*)/some/path/script.jsf?someId=(?!$1(?:$|[^0-9]))([0-9]*) /$2/some/path/script.jsf?someId=$2 [R]
```

The important part is

```
(?!$1(?:$|[^0-9]))
```

which asserts that the next sequence of characters cannot be exactly the number in `$1`. (The `$|[^0-9]` bit assures that trailing numbers are considered.)