# Comparing values in RewriteCond directive

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, pcre, httpd.conf

I have one test uri 'http://example.com/test1.test2'.   How I can fetch uri components test1 and test2 and compare them via RewriteCond directive?..

I tried like below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} http://example.com/(.*)\.(.*)
RewriteCond $1!=$2
```

But getting syntax error saying `$1!=$2` is not proper syntax..
Expecting this check to be done via RewriteCond directive..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare and rewrite URL with mod\_rewrite based on path and query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289007/compare-and-rewrite-url-with-mod-rewrite-based-on-path-and-query-string)

Comment: Hi Nic3500, thanks for redirecting.. I gone through that post but it deals with numbers. But mine is about character stings comparison. I still feel, both are different w.r.t. to search and compare.

Comment: You can put your solution as an answer.  It might help future usres and will show the question as answered.

Comment: In the page question, scroll down, you will see a TextArea (called Your Answer), and put it in there.

Comment: Hi Nic, thanks.. made it as answer..

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve this with following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^example.com(.*)\.(?!\1$) 

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]
```